# How to add default records to 2nd generation package

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package

all

We are generating 2nd generation package, and we want to release some out of box records, like we want to include some organization level setting records in package.

But it seems we don't have support to do this.
One way to do this is to insert such records in post installation script, but it looks quite not convenient.

Just want to know if there are other solutions, or how do you achieve this if you are using 2nd package as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question. Packages cannot include records, with the exception of Custom Metadata "records" (but these still count as metadata), so if you want to include some default data, the post-installation script is the correct place to create this data. This includes data that would be stored in Custom Settings.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation on this, regarding "with the exception of Custom Metadata records", how can we include them in package, is there any document on it?

Comment: @stanley Just create your CMDT (Custom Metadata Type) records in the UI, then retrieve the CMDT. If you're using a Scratch Org, or any org with Source Tracking, you can `force:source:pull` those records, just as you would any other metadata. The main documentation for these "records" is found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadata.htm).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for help.